# OOP variant for mysql_result?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I want the OOP/MySQLi variant for this code:

```
return mysql_result($result, 0);
```

... i have this code:

```
function mysql_evaluate($query, $default_value="undefined") {
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows < 1){
        return $default_value;
    } else {
        return mysql_result($result, 0);
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
return $result;
```

If you just want the first row, then:

```
return $result->fetch_object();
```

or

```
return $result->fetch_assoc();
```

depending on what you want back will do the job.

You aren't binding any variables into your $query, so this isn't particularly better than just using the mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of query call, mysqli_result object is returned.
Here is the full description of that type: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php
Probably $result->fetch_all() is what You are looking for.